# serverside git restrict branch creation to specific users

Tags: git, githooks, git-server

I'm thinking this needs to be done with some type of git hook.

On our central git server (where everybody merges to) - we have special (reserved) branch names, for example: any branch starting with RELEASE_ shall only be made by the CM team members as part of a formal release process.

I also need to block anyone from accidently commiting to that branch once it is created, ie: once a RELEASE has been made that RELEASE branch shall be read only in some form

This is not for malicious reasons, its just to stop stupid mistakes - we are all human and damn, shit happens just want to avoid and stop stupid mistakes before they bite the team in the ass and we have problems.

My question is, what GIT rule or hook can I create that will prevent this type of mistake from happening.  And can this be worked around with a 'force push'? (this is why I am thinking the server side is where it needs to be enforced)

If this is possible, can you point met to an example? (This is not a hard thing to do with SVN - where we are comming from, and the powers that be are asking this question of me and I can't answer that yet)

NOTE: I think this really needs to be on the server side, reason: The hook needs to support all users, both windows and linux and I dont' want somebody to try to fix/upgrade/whatever these types of security hooks on accident... (that stuff never happens right...)

Comment: You need a pre-receive or update hook. Depending on what you're doing on the server, you might already have one, and might need to set up something fancier. The pre-receive and update hooks don't get to see the `--force` flag so cannot affect it; if they reject the attempt to create a new branch name, `--force` doesn't help the person doing the `git push`.

Comment: To see a sample of a complex pre-receive hook (that will need modification for your purposes, plus testing) look at [this file](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt).

Comment: Confused about the "--force" thing - I've used that a few times to fix things when I had a GIT GURU guy working with me (previous company) now somewhere else and I'm mr git! (run for your life!) - SO QUESTION: Does --force override hook checks? And if so - how can I disallow --force pushes at the server

Comment: The force flag overrides Git's *internal* checks, but *is not passed to hooks*. This means hooks can't even tell whether someone used `--force` in the first place. It cannot affect the hook, it can only affect whether Git allows the request to get past the internal checks and arrive *at* the hook.

Comment: That sucks because you sometimes need to force

Comment: Yes, I know. I wish Git would export the per-branch force flag in some way (although how it should do that in a backwards-compatible fashion is another problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a pre-receive and either use ssh (or other OS-mediated) identities or if you need real security use signed commits, but the real source of awkwardness here is in your existing workflow: it's designed to fit within constraints that no longer apply.

Still, it's not hard to make Git work within those constraints, and probably a lot harder to get your to team adopt a new, unfamiliar workflow, so here's my seed pre-receive for vetting inbound commits:

```
#!/bin/bash --
# pre-receive hook to vet all inbound commits not in existing history

# collect all non-deleted tips, *[^0]* is any string w/ a nonzero
while read old new ref; do
    incoming+=("$old $new $ref")
    [[ $new = *[^0]* ]] && news="$news $new"
done

# vet each commit, id's via here-doc to keep shell environ access
while read commit; do
    check $commit here || hookrc=1
done <<EOD
$(  git rev-list $news --not --all  )
EOD

exit $hookrc
```

and it's easy enough to extend that in any direction you please. Use ssh for pushes that might need authorization and a workable idea is

```
if [[ $ref = refs/heads/RELEASE_* && ! -w update-release ]]
then hookrc=1; echo updating $ref needs authorization $USER does not have
fi
```

where you control updates on those refs by controlling write access to that file in the repo. Add authorized users to the file's group or acl, done.

But it's even easier to give each team a repo they administer themselves. The release team has a release repo, they can fetch anything they want to it and call it what they want, but nobody else can update it at all. The QA team has an incoming repo to which anyone can push and they control integration testing based off what shows up there. None of that needs to be cluttering up the main  project repo, it's for the *really* important stuff, currently-shipping release tags and the maintenance-base tip.

Comment: So what you are saying is - two repos (DEV, and RELEASE) then restrict write ability to the release repo.. and only allow READs from the unclean types.

Comment: Way I see it, that way's both easier to administer and cleaner for the users. But if your team's already got that old timey only-one-repo-can-be-real mindset baked in it might not seem that way to you, the prereceive and however you want to check auth might feel right, not my call.

Comment: So we'll use SSH/w KEYS so the assumption is the user is validated. My concern is the "--force" feature I have heard you can get around hooks with force. That would be bad...  But if there was a simple any push to a branch matching(SOME_REGEX) by people other then (IS_ConfigManagement) is Rejected is good enough for my needs

Comment: Do more digging. Anyone with filesystem write access unmediated by git can bypass anything git could ever do, that's why you can bypass local hooks. But you're the admin of your local repository and if you don't direct access on the server you do have to go through git. And Git doesn't provide a way to bypass those hooks.

Comment: I want the ability to diff release vrs branch (dev or feature) in an easy way but also need (require) the ability to protect the release branches from simple human fuckups everything will be on a server like bitbucket(unlikely) or gitlab(most likely)

Comment: Well, [gitlab has a protected branches feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html).